# С чем связано нарушение грамматических норм Лермонтовым в обороте «из пламя»? Только ли с необходимостью сохранить размер?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, поэзия

«НЕ ВСТРЕТИТ ОТВЕТА СРЕДЬ ШУМА ЛЮДСКОГО/ ИЗ ПЛАМЯ И СВЕТА РОЖДЕННОЕ СЛОВО». Мало можно найти в русской поэзии строк, сравнимых по красоте и силе  с этими крылатыми лермонтовскими строками. Они обладают такой экспрессией и энергией внушения, что не сразу замечаешь солецизм, резкое отступление от грамматической  нормы – «ИЗ ПЛАМЯ». Первым на это нарушение грамматики указал поэту редактор «Отечественных записок» Андрей Краевский. Писатель Иван Панаев вспоминает: Раз утром Лермонтов приехал к г. Краевскому в то время, когда я был у него. Лермонтов привез ему свое стихотворение: ЕСТЬ РЕЧИ — ЗНАЧЕНЬЕ/ ТЕМНО ИЛЬ НИЧТОЖНО… — прочел его и спросил: «Ну что, годится?..» — Еще бы! Дивная вещь! — отвечал г. Краевский, — превосходно; но тут есть в одном стихе маленький грамматический промах, неправильность… — Что такое? — спросил с беспокойством Лермонтов. — ИЗ ПЛАМЯ И СВЕТА /РОЖДЕННОЕ СЛОВО… Это неправильно, не так, — возразил г. Краевский, — по-настоящему, по грамматике надо сказать из пламени и света… — Да если этот пламень не укладывается в стих? Это вздор, ничего, — ведь поэты позволяют себе разные поэтические вольности — и у Пушкина их много… Однако… (Лермонтов на минуту задумался)… дай-ка я попробую переделать этот стих». Он взял листок со стихами, подошел к высокому фантастическому столу с выемкой, обмакнул перо и задумался… Так прошло минут пять. Мы молчали. Наконец Лермонтов бросил с досадой перо и сказал: «Нет, ничего нейдет в голову. Печатай так, как есть. Сойдет с рук…». Возникает вопрос: имеем ли мы здесь всего лишь одну дополнительную иллюстрацию к латинской пословице QUOD LICET IOVI (JOVI), NON LICET BOVI («Что дозволено Юпитеру, то не дозволено быку»), или здесь присутствует возможность иного толкования ситуации: подспудная  лингвоэстетическая мотивировка употребления формы «из пламя», по причине которой Лермонтов так и не смог исправить текст? Не потеряло бы в своей силе и образности это выражение и стихотворение в целом, если бы солецизм был бы устранен?

Answer (score 2):

У Лермонтова была развита языковая интуиция. Во многих русских говорах, в разговорной речи и, главное, в художественной практике ряда русских писателей XVIII — начала XIX века слова «имя», «время» и подобные им склоняются по образцу «поле». Живые народные формы этих слов относительно свободно употребляли Кантемир, Радищев, Державин, Крылов, Лермонтов и даже позднее Л. Н. Толстой в «Войне и мире». Подобная грамматическая форма встречается в произведениях Лермонтова: «Погаснувших от время и страстей» (стихотворение «1831-го, июня 11 дня»), «Не выглянет до время седина» (поэма «Сашка»), «Ни даже имя своего» (стихотворение «А. О. Смирновой», вариант из альбома М. П. Полуденского).

Существительные ср. р. на -мя (имя, семя и др.) и сейчас имеют в ряде говоров нерегулярные формы склонения, но в чистом виде такой тип склонения сохранился лишь в немногих говорах. Чаще он активно вытесняется каким-либо из основных типов склонения с обобщением основы во всех падежных формах. При этом обычно обобщается основа им. п. (им. имё или имя, род. имя или ими, дат. имю или име (ими) и т.д.). Существительные с этой основой могут относиться ко 2-му или к 1-му скл., а также и к промежуточному типу, разделяя в этом отношении судьбу других существительных ср. р. с ударением на основе.

А вообще история склонений существительных имеет довольно длинную историю. Сначала было 6 склонений, потом 4, потом 3 - главным образом за счет обобщения падежных окончаний, выражавших одни и те же грамматические значения. Процесс формирования новой системы именного склонения состоял, с одной стороны: в обобщении определенных падежных окончаний и их расширении в кругу существительных с разными древними основами, которым такие окончания ранее были несвойственны, с другой стороны: в закреплении вариантности окончаний у некоторых существительных, оказавшихся внутри одного и того же словоизменительного типа.

Середина XVII в. – XVIII в. – начальный период формирования национального русского языка,   18 век - Ломоносов отмечает 4 типа склонений имен существительных: 1, 2, 3 на -мя, 4 - из имен женского рода, на -ь («Российская грамматика» 1755).

В XIX в.их остаётся 3 +  выделяется группа разносклоняемых существительных, которые имеют падежные окончания разных склонений. В историческом отношении в эту группу входят слова ср. р. из древнего склонения на согласный с бывшим суффиксом -мен- (имя, время, племя и др.) и слово путь из древнего склонения на -ь.

Так что лермонтовские строки не противоречат по своей грамматической форме традиции русского литературного языка. Использование устаревших форм склонения существительных придаёт возвышенность речи.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ Людмилы  на мой вопрос был дан хороший и правильный. Но есть еще одно важное обстоятельство, которое, как представляется, повлияло на решительное интуитивное неприятие Лермонтовым рекомендуемой   правки. В результате замены формы родительного падежа (пламени) на форму именительного-винительного в препозиции по отношению к подлежащему СЛОВО у дополнения ИЗ ПЛАМЯ наряду с объектным значением появляется добавочное субъектное. Таким образов возникает  мерцание смысла и образная глубина: пламя не только то, из чего рождается слово, но еще и то, что само рождает его.

Comment: Согласна, это тоже присутствует

Comment: Очень любопытна динамика иконических оценок моего ответа. "Не встретит ответа..."? :)